# Rails web server not starting with rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 
ruby version 1.8.7
rails version 2.3.8

Ruby server is not starting up on executing following command.

```
    [root@localhost demo]# ruby script/server -p 80 -d
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:80
    [root@localhost demo]#
```

Why is this observed, how can it be resolved?

Comment: What response are you getting exactly ?

Comment: The same as above starting server is just exiting without any error. I checcked to confim if process is running by ps ax | grep ruby. There is no process named ruby running.

Comment: As a sanity check, can you remove the `-p 80` and `-d` options and see if there's anything running under `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: not sure why are you getting this, on which os platform you are trying this? If you are on a non root user of linux ubuntu and try to run the  rails server with port 80, it will close automatically. because port 80 is not available for non root users on linux ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah it was running in background, Iptables was running hence was not able to access the site over browser. Thanks guys for suggestions :)

Comment: the -d sends the process to the background it is running. Take off -d and you will see it is running.